# Error using ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetCimGateway with Authorize.Net's opaqueData

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorize.net, activemerchant, accept.js

Feb 8, 2018

My Ruby on Rails application has been successfully using `ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetCimGateway` with the payment type `:credit_card` for creating a customer profile with an embedded payment profile.

I'm now in the process of migrating to Authorize.Net's Accept.js which accepts credit card info directly sent from their hosted payment form and returns a payment nounce of type `COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT` that can be used for one time to create a payment transaction, customer profile, etc.

I constructed a `payment_profile` hash with `:opaque_data` in place of `:credit_card`. For example:

```
> payment_profile
=> {:payment=>
  {:opaque_data=>
    {:data_descriptor=>"COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT",
     :data_value=> "eyJjb2RlIjoiNTBfMl8wNjAwMDUzNjBDMzAwOUQ3OEUzOUQ1MDk4QTYxMjFGNzlCQ0Y3RDRGQUE4NTNCMEU3MkYyMUJBNTI3NUE0NjQ2Q0ZFQTVFNzMxMDI2Qjg5ODJGNjBFRUE2RDZFMTZCMUY5NzQ4NUJFIiwidG9rZW4iOiI5NTE4MDc3Njg5NDA4MTAwOTAzNTAyIiwidiI6IjEuMSJ9"}},
 :bill_to=>{:first_name=>"Firstname", :last_name=>"Lastname", :address=>nil, :city=>nil, :state=>nil, :zip=>nil, :country=>nil, :phone_number=>"(012) 234-5678"}}
```

I then tried to create a customer profile with an existing code similar to the following:

```
response = @gateway.create_customer_profile profile: {
  email: client.email,
  description: client.name,
  merchant_customer_id: client.id,
  payment_profiles: payment_profile
}
```

However, I received a response which had a `result_code` of `Error` and complained about "incomplete content" for element `payment` as follows:

```
> response
=> #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response:0x007f9827d14900
 @authorization=nil,
 @avs_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil, "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil},
 @cvv_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil},
 @emv_authorization=nil,
 @error_code="E00003",
 @fraud_review=nil,
 @message=
  "The element 'payment' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'creditCard, bankAccount, trackData, encryptedTrackData, payPal, opaqueData, emv' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.",
 @params=
  {"messages"=>
    {"result_code"=>"Error",
     "message"=>
      {"code"=>"E00003",
       "text"=>
    "The element 'payment' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'creditCard, bankAccount, trackData, encryptedTrackData, payPal, opaqueData, emv' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'."}}},
 @success=false,
 @test=true>
```

I have a few questions in my mind:

1. Does `ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetCimGateway` even support Accept.js' `:opaque_data` in place of `:credit_card`?
2. If `ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetCimGateway` does support `:opaque_data`, what's may be wrong with the above `payment_profile` and what other content that I'd need to provide for `payment` element?

I'd appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is over 4 years old, and I'm assuming you have either found a solution or abandoned your effort, I ran into this same issue recently, and thought it would be helpful to add my findings in case someone else runs into this.

the `AuthorizeNetCimGateway` does not currently support Accept.js' `opaqueData`. In looking at the sourcecode for the active_merchant gem, specifically in [/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/authorize_net_cim.rb](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/authorize_net_cim.rb), there is ultimately a method `add_payment_profile` that gets called. In that method, specifically on lines 759-761, you can see that the options are either a credit_card, bank_account, or drivers_license. A tokenized payment is not currently supported.

That being said, there is an open [PR#2422](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/pull/2422/files) that adds support for this. At the time of writing this, it appears to be failing some rubocop specs, but hopefully it can get deployed in the near future!

Comment: I no longer working on that code base. Thank you anyway for highlighting the PR, which is still open as of now.